# IP Phone Action URL (HTTP GET) to Windows 10 Event/Message

Tags: get, listener, sip, pbx

I have a VitalPBX instance hosted on a remote web server that connects to IP phones in my office (specifically Grandstream GXP1625 and Yealink T48S). We routinely use proprietary CRM software that I would like to be able to integrate with these phones. When I answer the phone, I would like the CRM software to open the client who is calling, so I do not have to manually type in the caller ID/telephone number to pull up the caller's information.

I use [Macro Express Pro 6](https://www.macros.com/) to automate many other repetitive processes with this CRM software, and I was hoping to use this macro software on computers next to phones to open the calling client. It supports macro activation through many avenues, including [system events/messages](https://www.macros.com/helppro/Topics/System_Event.htm).

Both of my IP phone models support something called Action URL, which sends a HTTP(S) GET request that can contain variables when certain actions occur, such as the phone initiating a call. I already have the companion feature, Action URI, set up so Macro Express Pro dials telephone numbers within my CRM on the phones directly.

-Yealink Action URL documentation is on page 465 of [this guide](http://support.yealink.com/previewPdf?file=http%3A%2F%2Fsupport.yealink.com%2Fforward2download%3Fpath%3DZIjHOJbWuW%2FDFrGTLnGypkTJASVqwzX%2F9pgN3D8plusSymbolR79dXhZ%2FgutXadj8MJtxG1PpEPhCxqfU55CGt8d5bPeCHO2vI0dfx5cajKnSs91tc2EuI6ejVgO8mTgplusSymbolwPl9kBKDC3K%2FL8kcCAlddUho%2FhX1NmANDkZakLiJSich3h11CGQlQplusSymbol47plusSymbolUOVAvm3k21taBVP5k2D5TlaEI76NteyNplusSymbol5LUA%3D%3D).

-Grandstream Action URL documentation is on page 91 of [this guide](http://www.grandstream.com/sites/default/files/Resources/gxp16xx_administration_guide.pdf).

I am looking for help in creating or repurposing a lightweight, opening at start-up, application to listen for and process these HTTP GET requests on my local Windows 10 machines and register a system event/message, including passing the Action URL variable, for Macro Express Pro to recognize and initiate a macro that will open my CRM to the proper patient. I believe this should be a simple task, though I am not familiar with this variety of programming. If an open-source software exists that can do this, I would love to hear. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1):

I successfully have the IP phones sending GET requests using [TCP/IP Builder](http://www.drk.com.ar/builder.php). Now just need to figure out how to have this program or a similar one send a system message.